# Demultiplexing using IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have one DependencyProperty X (String) and n DependencyProperties Yi (String), all of type String, where X is the concatenation of Yi for all i. Using a MultiValueConverter this can be achieved easily.

On the other hand, if x changes, I want to split x into chunks and assign each chunk (by some ruleset that depends on the chunk's data value) to its corresponding y_i.

For this, I need to know which index j of the Object[] that ConvertBack returns is connected to y_i.

So I am wondering: How can I get a reference to the source object to whose's property the j-th value in the returned Object[] in ConvertBack is assigned

My Convert-Method:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String cur;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cur = values[i] as String)) continue;

            if (b.Length != 0) b.Append(',');
            b.Append(cur);
        }

        return b.ToString();
    }
```

and the corresponding ConvertBack

```
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Object[] ret = new Object[targetTypes.Length];

        // How do I know which Source.Property the element
        // ret[i]
        // targets

    }
```

Comment: Your only other input into the `IValueConverter` is the `parameter` input parameter and you can't data bind that, so your options are very limited. You might need to rethink the situation... you could use a collection of `string`s in an `ItemsControl` (your `Y` items) that are rendered as `TextBlock`s that sit next to each other to give the impression that they are all in a single `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a general (and somewhat practical) solution that worked for me

I implemented ConvertBack in IMultiValueConverter as follows

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Object[] ret = new Object[targetTypes.Length];

    if(null != (value as String))
        for(Int32 i = 0; i < targetType.Length; i++)
        {
            // Propagate a copy of value to each Binding
            ret[i] = value.ToString();
        }

    return ret;
}
```

This distributes the provided value to each attached Yi. Since a MultiBinding is a 'collection' of Binding-s, one can attach an IValueConverter to each Binding. Each IValueConverter can be parameterized with some information regarding its attached source, so it can filter out any chunks that do not belong to the attached source.

Attached an example of an IValueConverter that uses data provided by parameter to filter out values

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(String), typeof(String))]
public sealed class ParameterFilter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(null == (parameter as String)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        if(null == (value as String)) return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        String[] split = value.ToString().Split(',');
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        String cur;

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cur = split[i])) continue;
            if(!cur.Contains(parameter.ToString()) continue;

            if (b.Length != 0) b.Append(',');
            b.Append(cur);
        }

        return b.ToString();
    }
}
```